convert column values into column name of dataframe in r
I have following dataframe:
Geber_Nr         Date              Time            Wert     
0101           2022-03-18        13:45:00          0.10 
0101           2022-03-18        14:09:00          0.00
0101           2022-03-18        14:20:00          0.50
0101           2022-03-18        14:31:00          0.00
0101           2022-03-18        14:41:00          0.00
0101           2022-03-18        14:46:00          0.00
0101           2022-03-19        00:00:00          0.00
0101           2022-03-19        00:01:00          0.00
0103           2022-03-18        13:45:00          0.00
0103           2022-03-18        14:09:00          0.00
0103           2022-03-18        14:20:00          0.00
0103           2022-03-18        14:31:00          0.00
0103           2022-03-18        14:41:00          0.00
0103           2022-03-18        14:46:00          0.00
0103           2022-03-19        00:00:00          0.00
0103           2022-03-19        00:01:00          0.00  
0104           2022-03-18        13:45:00          0.00
0104           2022-03-18        14:09:00          0.00
0104           2022-03-18        14:20:00          0.00
0104           2022-03-18        14:31:00          0.00
0104           2022-03-18        14:41:00          0.00
 .                 .                .               .
 .                 .                .               .
 .                 .                .               .


structure(list(Geber_Nr = c("0101", "0101", "0101", 
"0101", "0101", "0101", "0101", "0101", "0103", "0103", "0103", 
"0103", "0103", "0103", "0103", "0103", "0104", "0104", "0104", 
"0104", "0104", "0104", "0104", "0104", "0106", "0106", "0106", 
"0106", "0106", "0106"), Date = structure(c(19069, 19069, 19069, 
19069, 19069, 19069, 19070, 19070, 19069, 19069, 19069, 19069, 
19069, 19069, 19070, 19070, 19069, 19069, 19069, 19069, 19069, 
19069, 19070, 19070, 19069, 19069, 19069, 19069, 19069, 19069
), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(49500, 50940, 51600, 52260, 
52860, 53160, 0, 60, 49500, 50940, 51600, 52260, 52860, 53160, 
0, 60, 49500, 50940, 51600, 52260, 52860, 53160, 0, 60, 49800, 
50400, 51000, 51600, 52200, 52800), class = c("hms", "difftime"
), units = "secs"), Wert = c(0.1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 185.57, 185.57, 185.57, 
NA, NA, NA), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

How do I convert the column "Geber_Nr" into multiple column names with its corresponding values in column "Wert" as followed:
Date              Time              0101     0103    0104    0106
2022-03-18        13:45:00          0.10      NA      NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:09:00          0.00      NA      NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:20:00          0.50      NA      NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:31:00          0.00      NA      NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:41:00          0.00      NA      NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:46:00          0.00      NA      NA      NA
2022-03-19        00:00:00          0.00      NA      NA      NA
2022-03-19        00:01:00          0.00      NA      NA      NA
2022-03-18        13:45:00           NA      0.00     NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:09:00           NA      0.00     NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:20:00           NA      0.00     NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:31:00           NA      0.00     NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:41:00           NA      0.00     NA      NA
2022-03-18        14:46:00           NA      0.00     NA      NA
2022-03-19        00:00:00           NA      0.00     NA      NA
2022-03-19        00:01:00           NA      0.00     NA      NA  
2022-03-18        13:45:00           NA       NA     0.00     NA
2022-03-18        14:09:00           NA       NA     0.00     NA   
2022-03-18        14:20:00           NA       NA     0.00     NA 
2022-03-18        14:31:00           NA       NA     0.00     NA 
2022-03-18        14:41:00           NA       NA     0.00     NA  
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .

I have tried dcast (dcast(data, Date+Time~Geber_Nr, value.var="Wert") but it puts out only the amount of cells, where values exisit.
Can someone help me out?

I created a new column id, a copy of Geber_Nr to use in the id_cols= to keep the rows separate in the output, then drop this column at the end.
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id = Geber_Nr) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, Date, Time), names_from = Geber_Nr, values_from = Wert) %>%
  dplyr::select(-id)

